# AWS Glue Parallel writes to redshift table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to write 400M records to redshift table using write_dynamic_frame_from_jdbc_conf. Here is the sample code.

```
data = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "source_date") 

red_data= glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_jdbc_conf(frame=data,
                                                                      catalog_connection=connection,
                                                                      connection_options={
                                                                          "dbtable": "table_name",
                                                                          "database": "db"
                                                                      },
                                                                      redshift_tmp_dir="s3:/xxx",
                                                                      transformation_ctx="red_data"
                                                                      )
```

This is taking around 6 to 8hours to load data into redshift table.

How do we partition/distribute data so that it will have parallel tasks to load data into redshift table.

Any insights on this greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Bab